# Access an MS Access database stored in google drive using VBA

Tags: vba, google-drive-api

I there any way to access the database that is stored in Google drive?

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to use a real DB?

Comment: I agree but the database need to updated by multiple ppl across location I just want an idea or suggestion how to use Google drive as a common database for Excel as a frond end as we are not having any drive I am using Google drive as share path across locations.

Comment: so if excel is the front end, why can't you use google spreadsheets? Sorry, but it seems like you're approaching this all backwards...

Comment: We need Excel as front end and it will create PDF files based on the data on the excel sheets some of those data need to be taken from google spread sheet.

Comment: My main theme is I need an excel sheet for order generation will fill the required details in the excel and then will convert the sheet into PDF to send to customer.So there is one drop down which will have list of products of the company once selecting the product from the drop down the product desc and price will be displayed in the excel form this price may be updated timely across different locations this is the scenario and I need to use excel as front end and any thing that I can use as a DB using google drive and common share path.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [Drive File Stream](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7491144?hl=en)?

By doing this, you can have your MSAccess files with a local path (ie: "G\My Drive\MyDB...")